# Accessing a single property in a JSON object

Tags: json, key

I am trying to access "token" inside of "tokens" array and set that token as the {{authToken}}.  in Postman but I am having trouble with the proper syntax.

I tried this

```
if (pm.response.code === 201) {
    pm.environment.set('authToken', pm.response.json().tokens["token"])
}
```

```
{
 "idVerified": false,
    "idZip": 0,
    "subscription": 0,
    "emailVerified": false,
    "_id": "600f3cca17d9e88b126872cc",
    "username": "authtestx",
    "name": "JOHN",
    "email": "TEST@gmail.com",
    "tokens": [
        {
            "_id": "600f3cca17d9e88b126872cd",
            "token":    "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2MDBmM2NjYTE3ZDllODhiMTI2ODcyY2MiLCJpYXQiOjE2MTE2MTEzMzgsImV4cCI6MTYxMjA0MzMzOH0.2gChzDVG-IvxlHE8JSm0p9MkQHBmzePy70UqewbUNQ0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ur really close, since tokens is an array accessing the first element like this might do it

```
if (pm.response.code === 201){
pm.environment.set('authToken', pm.response.json().tokens[0].token)
}
```

i have tried it here, have a look : https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GN2I6QBQYVFO